# Migration JBoss AS 7.1.1 to Wildfly 8.1.0 - error: java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly-8

I am trying to migrate a project from JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final to Wildfly 8.1.0 Final. But I am getting the error **java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager"**.

I already tried removing references from **hibernate-commons-annotations** from maven, but it didn't work.

I read  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127431/spring-java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-loader-previously-in) and [this article](https://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html) and understood that it is a complex problem. The system is trying to load the same class twice. I think that the problem occurs because of some library conflict between wildfly library and my project, but I can't find that.

I am using Oracle JDk 1.7, Maven, CDI, Hibernate.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Log error:

```
2018-11-28 16:56:39,812 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Failed to define class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager in Module "deployment.controledeacesso-sapbm.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.RevisionInfoConfiguration.configure(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:256) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.<init>(AuditConfiguration.java:95) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:135) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:63) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
2018-11-28 16:56:39,812 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."controledeacesso-sapbm.war#default": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."controledeacesso-sapbm.war#default": java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager"
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.RevisionInfoConfiguration.configure(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:256) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.<init>(AuditConfiguration.java:95) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:135) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:63) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 8 more
```

These are the files in folder WEB-INF/lib

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
bootstrap-1.0.10.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-email-1.3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.3.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ControledeAcessoClient.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
3.hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.1.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar
jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mail-1.4.5.jar
3.ojdbc7.jar
org.apache.commons.lang-2.6.jar
postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc3.jar
2.primefaces-4.0.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

Comment: Just curious - is Wildfly 8 not closer to JBoss 6, therefore you’re migrating to an older version equivalent than JBoss 7?

Comment: Actually I would like to migrate to Wildfly 9, but Wildfly 8 and 9 show the same error.

Comment: Can you please list the jars which are inside of your `war`. Also if you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml ` add it

Comment: I edited the topic and put all the jars files. There is no jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my project.

Comment: Try removing the hibernate libraries from your deployment. There really are others that should be removed as well like the jaxrs-api, dom4j, jboss-logging, etc.

Comment: I removed from pom.xml: hibernate-validator, hibernate-core, hibernate-commons-annotations, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and jta. The problem persist.